# Selenium Compound class names not permitted

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, class-names

I have the below code that clicks on an element to pop up a screen and copy the text in it

```
el1 = driver.find_element_by_id("keyDev-A")
el1.click()
el2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("content")
print(el2.text)
```

However, when I tried to get `selenium` to click on the button within that popup with

```
el3 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "action-btn cancel alert-display")
el3.click()
```

It produces an error message:

```
invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

This is the HTML that I am trying to get `selenium` to click on. The `Close` button.

```
<div class="nav">
    <span class="action-btn confirm prompt-display">Confirm</span>
    <span class="action-btn cancel prompt-display">Cancel</span>
    <span class="action-btn cancel alert-display">Close</span>
</div>
```

How should I be writing `el3` in order to click on the **Close** button?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658907/selenium-python-find-element-by-class-name-stopped-working-from-v-2-2-to-2-21 ? It might help.

Comment: Selenium does not support `BY.CLASS_NAME` with **compound class**..you need to use `cssSelector` or `XPath` to find `el3` here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Compound Class name error in Page Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808521/how-to-avoid-compound-class-name-error-in-page-object)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[Leon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted#comment63011467_37771604) leads to the correct information that compound class names are no longer supported. What you could do instead is try using css selectors. In your case, the following line of code should help you get the element you want :

```
el3 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".action-btn.cancel.alert-display")
```

For newer Selenium Versions

```
el3 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".action-btn.cancel.alert-display")
```

It finds the element with all three classes (action-btn, cancel and alert-display) in the class attribute. Do note that the order of the classes does not matter here and any of the classes may appear anywhere in the class attribute. As long as the element has all three classes, it will be selected.
If you want the order of the classes to be fixed, you can use the following xpath :

```
el3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='action-btn cancel alert-display']")
```

Comment: In 2023, this is the best solution, but the API has changed: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".action-btn.cancel.alert-display")`

Answer (score 3):

I am late to this question. But I also found a work around by treating the compound classes as a String, using tag_name, and get_attribute('class'), when you are not familiar with Xpath. It needs some more lines of code but it's straight forward and fit for beginners like me.

```
   elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('Tag Name Here')
        for element in elments:
            className = watchingTable.get_attribute('class')
            print(className)
                if className == 'Your Needed Classname':
                    #Do your things
```

Comment: After using this way for a short while. I found that it's may not be a good solution. Because when the TagName is 'DIV' or 'SPAN', you will have to go through the whole document each time you try to locate the element which is too heavy. Besides, when the page is loading, you may have to add some Try Except error handles to get rid of the annoying exceptions. Learn and get acquaintance with sagarwadhwa1's answer  suggests will be the good practise.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here are incorrect :

If you check the exception from the by_class_name:

[image]

you can see it is using css under the hood

by_class_name just adds '.' infront of the locator provided so 'a' will be passed as '.a' and a.b will be passed as '.a.b'

So You can use class_name for multiple classes , just need to replace space with '.'

so "a b c" should be passed as "a.b.c"

Eg:

**Working example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579491/find-element-by-class-name-in-selenium-giving-error/65579606?noredirect=1#comment115946541_65579606")
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('overflow-x-auto.ml-auto.-secondary.grid.ai-center.list-reset.h100')

print(elem.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

...implies that [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) using [Compound class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022) are not valid while using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

Traces of this change can be confirmed from the [Selenium v2.40.0 changelist](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) where the change log mentions about adding proper error code for compound class name usage:

> - Implemented proper error code for the case of invalid css selector    empty class name, and compound class name in atoms.

---

### Solution

As an alternative you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.action-btn.cancel.alert-display").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='action-btn cancel alert-display']").click()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to locate an element with multiple classnames using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534244/how-to-locate-an-element-with-multiple-classnames-using-selenium-and-python/60534315#60534315)

Answer (score 0):

Manually intersect the results for multiple classes.

```
def find_element_multi_class(driver, classes):
    elements = []
    for i,c in enumerate(classes):
        if i == 0:
            elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, c)
        else:
            new_elems = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, c)
            elements = list(set(elements) & set(new_elems))
    return elements
```