# find_element_by_class_name class spaces does not work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use `find_element_by_class_name` where the class has spaces and it does not work:

Here is the code:

```
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" href="/user/santanderbrasil">Santander Brasil</a>
```

I want the get the content "Santander Brasil"

I tried the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string")    
driver.find_element_by_class_name("a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string")
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("a.yt-simple-endpoint.")
```

none of the worked...

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted)

Answer (score 4):

Use the css selector function instead.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string")
```

Comment: This printed something. But not what I wanted tho. I forgot to mention that The content I want to scrap comes from an AJAX.
I want to get the content from the first banner that shows on the home of youtube.

Comment: This is the code that I can see when I inspect Elemen at the content I want to scrap on www.youtube.com: If you try on your yuotube it will be a different content because it´s a local AD. 

<div id="right-container" class="style-scope ytd-video-masthead-ad-advertiser-info-renderer">
   <div id="title-container" class="style-scope ytd-video-masthead-ad-advertiser-info-renderer">
      <yt-formatted-string id="title" class="style-scope ytd-video-masthead-ad-advertiser-info-renderer x-scope yt-formatted-string-1">Tudo no app, tudo na mão!</yt-formatted-string>

Answer (score 3):

Those are three separated classes, `find_element_by_class_name()` receives only one class as parameter. For example

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('yt-simple-endpoint')
```

The `.` you added between the classes represent `class` in `css_selector`. You can use it to locate the element by all three classes use `css_selector`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string')
```

Or by `xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'yt-simple-endpoint') and contains(@class, 'style-scope') and contains(@class, 'yt-formatted-string')]"")
```

Not sure about the find_element_by_xpath method because i don't use selenium in python, but whatever that function is, selector should do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All of these work for me (Firefox driver):

```
yt-simple-endpoint
style-scope
yt-formatted-string
yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string
```

Note that the last class name is actually the same as the first one in your question. It works because Selenium internally converts the class name into a CSS selector and then uses it for the search. If you want to nail things down for specific tags, e.g. only match `<a>` tags with those classes then you will need to look at CSS selectors and other options such as XPath.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("file:///tmp/test.html")

for class_name in 'yt-simple-endpoint', 'yt-formatted-string', 'style-scope', 'yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string':
    e = driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
    print(e.text)
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
Santander Brasil
Santander Brasil
Santander Brasil
Santander Brasil
```

The `test.html` file contains:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" href="/user/santanderbrasil">Santander Brasil</a>
</body>
</html>
```