# How to get the spoiler text from this web page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape user reviews off an IMDB page.

Specifically this one: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0993846/reviews?ref_=tt_ql_3

```
Reviews = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content')
Print(Reviews[0].text)
```

The code above gets me the first review just fine.

However, the 5th review titled "**Good or Bad depending on what you want...**"  is a spoiler review and this method does not seem to grab the text.

I have tried using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('text show-more__control clickable')
```

But this doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted)

Comment: BEFORE you ask a question, you should start by googling the error message and working through the questions and answers and try the various solutions. Then if you still can't find a solution, you should ask your question and make sure to add the full error message to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css selector hopefully this will return all reviews on the page.

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".review-container"):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: This only grabs the title for the spoiler review. It doesn't seem to get the review itself. I think it might not have loaded until you click "show review". I might have to have the program click it.