# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element error using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate a login on my website using selenium.

I am accessing this website : http://front-desk.fr/users/accounts/login/?next=/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\gaeta\OneDrive\Bureau\chromedriver.exe"

class FrontDesk:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("http://front-desk.fr/users/accounts/login/")
        time.sleep(5)
        email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('textinput textInput form-control')
        email.send_keys(self.username)



ed = FrontDesk('myemail@gmail.com', 'password1234')
ed.login()
```

But an error occur :

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".textinput textInput 
>   form-control"}

This is my website so I am sure of the class, and I have looked on SO and the answers were talking about Iframe, I do not have any.

I have tried with class, id etc. everything work except it does not fill the input.

Comment: Compound class names are not permitted.
Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted)

Comment: @hiropon Thanks ! I used a different kind of filter and it works now, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".textinput textInput form-control"}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the desired element with in the **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- Using `find_element_by_class_name()` you won't be able to pass multiple class names. Passing multiple classes you will face the error as:

  ```
  Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  ```
- You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted using find_element_by_class_name with Webdriver and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-using-find-element-by-class/53536022#53536022)
- You could have used the following CSS_SELECTOR as a valid selector instead:

  ```
  email = bot.find_element_by_css_selector('input.textinput.textInput.form-control')
  ```
- But the CSS_SELECTOR above doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely.

---

To send a *character sequence* within the **Identifiant** field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#id_login"))).send_keys(self.username)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='id_login']"))).send_keys(self.username)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### tl; dr

You can find a relevant detailed discussion on **NoSuchElementException** in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score -2):

The HTML source is not valid, there are plenty of unclosed tags such as those for your stylesheets. Fix these up then try again.

Comment: Hmm I don't where you're going with that... it's valid, selenium is just looking for id or tag... 

I managed to make it work by calling with the "name" filter.

I must say, your answer is not useful.

Comment: Try putting the html through an xml validator and you'll see what I mean with regards to it being invalid because of the unclosed tags. This is no longer important as you've solved your issue.