# Why am I not able to locate element in Flipkart using classname attribute?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using "class name" attribute to locate element in Flip-kart like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("_1QZ6fC _3Lgyp8"));
```

**The error I am getting is:**

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: ._1QZ6fC\ _3Lgyp8

**HTML code of the element is as follows:**

```
<span class="_1QZ6fC _3Lgyp8">Electronics<svg width="4.7" height="8" viewBox="0 0 16 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="_3ynUUz"><path d="M16 23.207L6.11 13.161 16 3.093 12.955 0 0 13.161l12.955 13.161z" fill="#fff" class="_3Der3h"></path></svg></span>
```

Target webelement and website - The "Electronics" category of the header in the URL https://www.flipkart.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the above line produces the following error:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted

Regarding this you can find more details from this earlier query [Selenium Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted)

Besides using the classname option in the specified page will result in the selection of multiple elements, as we can see there are atleast 7 items having the same classname.

Instead of this, you can use xpath to locate the element, something like the following:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Electronics')]"));