# click youtube button selenium python check my code

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I am trying to click using class to video on youtube

In this page https://likesrock.com using this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://likesrock.com")

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-large-play-button ytp-button")
element.click()
```

but the compilor give me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\youssef\Desktop\python project\xpath.py", line 25, in 
>       element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-large-play-button ytp-button")
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 413, in find_element_by_class_name
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .ytp-large-play-button ytp-button

please help

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10658907/7023590).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using compound classes in `find_element_by_class_name` which won't work. Change it to `find_element_by_xpath` and try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")
```

Note :- Your element is under `iFrame` so don't forgot to switch in `iframe`

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

Complete Code :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://likesrock.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(20) 
driver.switch_to.frame(0) 
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")
element.click()
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help i will not forget it just i added time.sleep(5) and it works

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input')
search_bar.send_keys("python")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just attempting to play the video by launching Youtube website.

Code provided by @Narendra worked well with Chrome but couldn't work with Firefox.

```
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("player-container")
element.click()
```

Above code worked with Firefox as well.