# Python Selenium Chrome Driver doesnt find elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a python selenium script. I find some elements in firefox by the command :

```
large_bu = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('butik.large.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-xs-12')
```

and `len(large_bu)` returns 20.

But when i try this in Chrome Driver `len(large_bu)` `returns 0`. 
How can i find this elements in Chrome Driver ?

Thanks for your replies. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you sure that class name attribute value looks like `"butik.large.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-xs-12"` (divided by dot, but not space)? Share HTML for the same.

Comment: `<div class="butik large col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" onclick="setHomePage`

Comment: This works for Firefox drivers. But Chrome drivers didn't find elements

Comment: also i have some time.sleep()  for elements located. there is no problem for firefox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is an issue between different versions of selenium.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658907/selenium-python-find-element-by-class-name-stopped-working-from-v-2-2-to-2-21) `find_elements_by_class_name` doesn't allow multiple classes anymore, you should use `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.butik.large.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-xs-12')
```

That should return a list with all the matches for that CSS selector.

Comment: Works in Chrome Driver. But the other format works in firefox driver...Does element search queries differ between different browser?

Comment: @DeepakM It doesn't surprise me that the other version works in Firefox, the capabilities change depending on which browser you're using or which version of the WebDriver you're on. If you're using the correct format for the browser you're on, the number of elements should be the same.