# Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to print one of my messages from a chat via webWhatsapp.

I was able to do it via Javascript from the Console tab i did it this way

```
recived_msg = document.getElementsByClassName('XELVh selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text') // returns an array of the chat
recived_msg[5].innerText // shows me the 4th message content
```

The problem is that i tried to do same thing on python but it doesnt work for me..

Heres what i tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
recived_msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('XELVh selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text')
final = recived_msg[5].innerText #doesnt work for some reason
```

my Error that i'm getting is: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

I'm kinda new to javascript so sorry for missunderstanding and thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the documentation of [**`selenium.webdriver.common.by`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation:

```
class selenium.webdriver.common.by.By
    Set of supported locator strategies.

    CLASS_NAME = 'class name'
```

So,

- Using `find_element_by_class_name()` you won't be able to pass multiple class names. 
  Passing multiple classes you will face the error as:

  ```
  Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  ```
- Additionally, as you want to return an array of the chats, so instead of `find_element*` you need to use **`find_elements*`**

---

### Solution

As an alternative you can use either of :the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  recived_msg = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".XELVh.selectable-text.invisible-space.copyable-text")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  recived_msg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='XELVh selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text']")
  ```

Comment: Thanks alot!, I was'nt sure about these and it very helped me :)

Answer (score -1):

Use ***css selector*** as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043877/compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-webdriver) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808521/how-to-avoid-compound-class-name-error-in-page-object)

```
recived_msg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('XELVh.selectable-text.invisible-space.copyable-text')
```