# Unable to find `class` on a Google page using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to push a button on a Google web page, but selenium can't locate it.

Here's how the page appears:
[image]

Here's the html:

https://search.google.com/search-console/about

```html
<span class="RveJvd snByac">Start now</span>
```

Here's the code:

```py
def show_webpage(judge_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(SITE)
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('RveJvd snByac')
    button_element[1].click()

    html_source = driver.page_source

    driver.close()
    return html_source
```

And this is the error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
selector","selector":".RveJvd snByac"}
```

Comment: `RveJvd` and `snByac` are two classes. Space is a delimiter in the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Micheal said, the find_element_by_class_name takes only one class name at a time as argument. you are passing two. if you want to use two class name then you can use css selector instead as given below.

```
def show_webpage(judge_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(SITE)
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.RveJvd.snByac')
    button_element[1].click()

    html_source = driver.page_source

    driver.close()
    return html_source
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing multiple *classNames* within `find_element_by_class_name()` will result in [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted using find_element_by_class_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-using-find-element-by-class/53536022#53536022)

Moreover, the *classnames* e.g. **RveJvd**, **snByac**, etc looks dynamic.

However, to click on the button with text as **Start now** on the Google web page `https://search.google.com/search-console/about` you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://search.google.com/search-console/about")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Improve your performance on Google Search']//following::div[1]//span[text()='Start now']"))).click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Most probably these class names are changing each time the page is loaded, you should rather stick to `Start now` text of the [span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) tag
2. There is no guarantee that the element will be immediately available in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) so consider using [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to ensure that the document is there

Suggested code change:

```
driver.get("https://search.google.com/search-console/about")

start_now = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Start now']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", start_now)
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)