# How to click that element with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

It's clickable when i login without automazied test even it's a text

I tried :

```
element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-inquiry-main/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/app-tuselection/div/div[2]')))
element2.click()
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Please [EDIT] your question with text based html and better to share URL of the webpage.

Comment: click : enter image description here
i 've added an image of the text based html 
but i can't share the url

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to click element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.navlinks.ng-star-inserted > div > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='navlinks ng-star-inserted']//span[text()='050 ENGINE ATTACHMENT PARTS']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```