# How to find search area using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this html:

```
<input _wad-f341 type="text" autocomplete="off" kkwdnkwn class="classname" placeholder="Search  here" id="ppui-search-0-input">
```

Using developer tools I am getting the xpath and  I am using below code to check if the search area is loaded or not.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ppui-search-0-input']")))
```

I am getting timeout as element was not found. Can anyone please help me?
Is there any other way apart from id like using the placeholder desription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally to locate a ***clickable*** element instead of [presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.classname[placeholder='Search  here'][id^='ppui-search']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='classname' and @placeholder='Search  here'][starts-with(@id, 'ppui-search')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```