# What is the correct element to use from this section of html?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium to automatically go to various webpages and download an XML file.
This has been working fine but it has suddenly stopped working, and it's due to selenium not being able to find the element.
I've tried using selector gadget with CSS & Xpath. I've tried directly copying from the inspect panel, I've tried using the wait function on selenium until the element fully shows and I'm getting no luck.

This is the html of where the download button is

```
<div class="video-playlist-xml" data-reactid=".2.0"><a href="#" data-reactid=".2.0.0"><i class="icon-download-xml-green" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Download xml file of the match" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0"></i></a></div>
```

The download button is just above the video, above the scoreline.
[image: With the XML button being just above the video, over the score-line.]

```
for x in range(number_of_clicks):
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Desktop\webdriver\chromedriver.exe',options = options)
   driver.get('https://football.instatscout.com/teams/978/matches')
   time.sleep(10)
   print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title) 
   WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#team-table1 > div.table-scroll-inner > div.team-stats-wrapper.team-stats-wrapper_no-vertical-scroll > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" +str(x+1) + ") > td:nth-child(1) > div > div.styled__MatchPlay-sc-10ytjn2-1.hkIvhi > i"))).click()
   WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#root > div > article > section.player-details > div > div.OutsideClickWrapper-sc-ktqo9u.cTxKts > div > a:nth-child(1) > span > span"))).click()
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.video-playlist-xml > a[href] > i.icon-download-xml-green[data-original-title='Download xml file of the match']"))).click()
   chks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#players > div.control-block > div.control-block__container.control-block__container--large > button")
   for chk in chks:
       chk.click()
       time.sleep(15)
       driver.quit()
```

error Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26436/2420202332.py in <module>
      6    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#team-table1 > div.table-scroll-inner > div.team-stats-wrapper.team-stats-wrapper_no-vertical-scroll > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" +str(x+1) + ") > td:nth-child(1) > div > div.styled__MatchPlay-sc-10ytjn2-1.hkIvhi > i"))).click()
      7    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#root > div > article > section.player-details > div > div.OutsideClickWrapper-sc-ktqo9u.cTxKts > div > a:nth-child(1) > span > span"))).click()
----> 8    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.video-playlist-xml > a[href] > i.icon-download-xml-green[data-original-title='Download xml file of the match']"))).click()
      9    #WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "video-playlist-xml", " " ))]//a | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "icon-download-xml-green", " " ))]'))).click()
     10    chks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#players > div.control-block > div.control-block__container.control-block__container--large > button")

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: @TimRoberts I've edited my main post to include. It's a little messy, and it's behind a subscription wall so not totally reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate a ***clickable*** element instead of [presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.video-playlist-xml > a[href] > i.icon-download-xml-green[data-original-title='Download xml file of the match']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='video-playlist-xml']/a[@href]/i[@class='icon-download-xml-green' and @data-original-title='Download xml file of the match']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thanks for the reply - i've tried your suggestion but I'm getting a TimeoutException

Comment: Can you update the question with the current error stacktrace?

Comment: I've just done this, and updated the original code, to make it a little more streamline.

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly, I've just realised that clicking one of the elements was opening a new window. Issues solved. Thanks guys.

Comment: Even after window switching ideally you need to use the code block from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70042025/7429447)