# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Click' error trying to Click on a link using Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, webdriverwait, expected-condition

So I am in the process of trying to reach a search page which involves clicking on a clickable link on the bottom of the page. My code seems to be able to find the link or at least not throw an error when attempting to, however I get the error "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Click'" even though the element is physically clickable on the page.
Here is the code and website.

```
driver = webdriver.Edge(r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Anaconda/edgedriver_win32/msedgedriver')
driver.get("https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/species-risk-public-registry/cosewic-assessments-status-reports")
#click on the "Search COSEWIC status reports" button
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search COSEWIC status reports"))
)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search COSEWIC status reports");
link.Click();
```

If I am wrong about this element being clickable please let me know.  To be clear I am trying to click on the link "Search COSEWIC status reports found at the bottom of the webpage "https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/species-risk-public-registry/cosewic-assessments-status-reports"

### Update

I have found a workaround but the question still remains.
I have run into another attribute that needs clicking and it doesn't seem to have attributes 'id' or anything easy to identify by.

```
<span data-v-7ee3c58f="" class="name-primary">COSEWIC Status Appraisal Summary on the Pacific Water Shrew <em>Sorex bendirii</em> in Canada</span>
```

I have tried copying the XPath to this element and the id within the XPath but they don't seem to work. this is the first result on the page. "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/documents?documentTypeId=18&sortBy=documentTypeSort&sortDirection=asc&pageSize=10&keywords=pacific%20water%20shrew"

Comment: Which programming language you are using. If its python, you don't need `semi-colon` and to click its `click()` with small letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language bing is [python](/questions/tagged/python) so instead of `Click()` you need to use [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251)

Additionally, to click on a ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver = webdriver.Edge(r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Anaconda/edgedriver_win32/msedgedriver')
driver.get("https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/species-risk-public-registry/cosewic-assessments-status-reports")
#click on the "Search COSEWIC status reports" button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search COSEWIC status reports"))).click()
```

Comment: Oh interesting, it seems there are a few different syntax things to look out for over selenium. Thanks for that. As for as the selection goes, the element I want to click now is this. `<span data-v-7ee3c58f="" class="name-primary">COSEWIC Status Appraisal Summary on the Pacific Water Shrew <em>Sorex bendirii</em> in Canada</span>`  I have tried by link text and partial link text also by class name as that is present although there are two with the same name and I cant seem to index the first one with `[0]`. I don't understand XPath or CSS though I have tried copying XPath. Didn't work