# Make Selenium wait until text is available

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to scrape some data from this website:
https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etf/ishares-core-s-p-500-ucits-etf-usd-acc

My script works but I need to impose a 5 seconds wait time to be sure that the data is actually available, otherwise I sometimes (randomly) get a blank result.

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
bid = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-wrapper/div/div[2]/app-etp/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/app-widget-quote-box/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]").text
print(bid)
```

I tried to use Selenium's wait function, but the script runs quickly with a blank result:

```
driver.get(url)
try:
    bid = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/app-wrapper/div/div[2]/app-etp/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/app-widget-quote-box/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]"))
    )
    bid = bid.text
    print(bid)
finally:
    pass
```

Any idea of how to make Selenium wait just the time necessary to scrape the data?
Thanks

---

Update:
A simple while cycle seems to work:

```
driver.get(url)
while driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text == "":
   pass
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Where are you waiting 5 seconds?

Comment: The script in the question is the one without the explicit 5 seconds time.sleep command

Comment: So your current wait checks that a `td` element exists in the page at the given xpath. That doesn't guarantee that the `td` element has text in it. If the page has JavaScript with adds text to that element, then you potentially will try to do `bit.text` before it executes. You need to modify your wait to make sure that the text is actually present.

Comment: I see that Selenium has a "text_to_be_present_in_element" condition, but i need to specify what the text is expected to be so doesn't help me. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: That simple while loop seems fine, I guess what do you mean by "better way"?

Comment: I was wondering if there a specific condition built inside Selenium, but you are right: the while loop does the trick

Comment: Please post your solution in the section below for answers rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate a ***visible*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get(url)
try:
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/app-wrapper/div/div[2]/app-etp/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/app-widget-quote-box/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]"))).text)
finally:
    pass
```