# Selenium can't find element by classname

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to check new notification, but selenium can't find it.

This is part of page code:

```
<div class="notifications">
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/Zhigalko_Sergei">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content">
            <span><strong>GM Zhigalko_Sergei</strong><time class="set" title="03.12.2021, 18:14:12" datetime="1638544452664">9 минут назад</time></span>
            <span>Дорогие Друзья!! NEW!! Сегодня 3 ДЕКАБРЯ…</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/EternalDance">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content">
            <span><strong>EternalDance</strong><time class="set" title="03.12.2021, 04:24:13" datetime="1638494653285">13 часов назад</time></span>
            <span>si</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/EternalDance">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content">
            <span><strong>EternalDance</strong><time class="set" title="03.12.2021, 04:23:52" datetime="1638494632534">13 часов назад</time></span>
            <span>fu</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/EternalDance">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content">
           <span><strong>EternalDance</strong><time class="set" title="03.12.2021, 04:22:22" datetime="1638494542415">14 часов назад</time></span>
           <span>f</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/EternalDance">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content"><span><strong>EternalDance</strong><time class="set" title="03.12.2021, 04:14:20" datetime="1638494060965">14 часов назад</time></span>
            <span>Hi</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/Zhigalko_Sergei">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content">
            <span><strong>GM Zhigalko_Sergei</strong><time class="set" title="30.11.2021, 19:17:27" datetime="1638289047224">2 дня назад</time></span>
            <span>Дорогие Друзья!! Сегодня 30 Ноября в 23:…</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="site_notification privateMessage" href="/inbox/Zhigalko_Sergei">
        <i data-icon=""></i>
        <span class="content">
            <span><strong>GM Zhigalko_Sergei</strong><time class="set" title="27.11.2021, 19:05:46" datetime="1638029146777">5 дней назад</time></span>
            <span>Дорогие Друзья!! Сегодня 27 Ноября в 22:…</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    option = Options()

    option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    option.add_argument("start-maximized")
    option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

    option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
    })

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=option)
    driver.get('https://lichess.org/login')
    username_form = driver.find_element_by_id('form3-username')
    password_form = driver.find_element_by_id('form3-password')
    username_form.send_keys('Mylogin')
    password_form.send_keys('Mypassword')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='one-factor']/button").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'notify-toggle'))
    ).click()

    new_inventation = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "site_notification privateMessage"))
    )
```

But Selenium can't find it. I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

[*By.CLASS_NAME*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CLASS_NAME) accepts a single classname. So you can't pass multiple classnames. Moreover, the *notification* seems to be a visible element.

To locate a ***visible*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  new_inventation = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notifications']//a[@class='site_notification privateMessage']//span[@class='content'][./span[contains(., 'NEW')]]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```