# Python Selenium - Get href link

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the Facebook link from a website href element, but keep getting errors.
Here is the HTML from its website:

```
   <li class="ssi-facebook">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/YMCA-of-Central-Massachusetts/165183010213237?sk=wall" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      </a>
    </li>
```

and here is the code I've tried:

```
elems = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'ssi-facebook')))
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
print(links)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider:

- The *href* link is within the child *A* of the parent *LI*
- As you are dealing with only one element instead of element(s) you can look for the unique element.
- To print the *href* attribute, as the desired element is a  element i.e.  a ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.ssi-facebook > a[href]"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ssi-facebook']/a[@href]"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I am more understanding about getting attributes using css selector. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

An `li` tag does not have an `href` attribute, an `a` tag does.

You can use the below CSS selector instead

```
elems = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.ssi-facebook a')))
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
print(links)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I really appreciate it.