# How to get time from website on selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to get the time from: https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/gts/time/clock_e.html

currently my code is:

```
timeDriver.get("https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/gts/time/clock_e.html")
HKTime = WebDriverWait(timeDriver,3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]'))).text
print(HKTime)
```

However, it is printing nothing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate a ***visible*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/gts/time/clock_e.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#hkoClock_Time"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/gts/time/clock_e.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='hkoClock_Time']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  am 07:14:03
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Use `visibility_of_element_located()` instead of `presence_of_element_located()` and following `css selector` to identify the element.

```
driver.get("https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/gts/time/clock_e.html")

print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#hkoClock_Time'))).get_attribute("innerText"))
print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#hkoClock_Time'))).text)
```

Or you can use following `xpath` as well

```
driver.get("https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/gts/time/clock_e.html")

print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="hkoClock_Time"]'))).get_attribute("innerText"))
print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="hkoClock_Time"]'))).text)
```