# Selenium wait for progress bar Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I still not get it with waiting progress bar with selenium for next code

```
<div data-v-a5395076="" class="progress">
<div data-v-a5395076="" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="98.4" 
aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" 
style="width: 98.4%;">98.4%</div>
```

this is what I'm trying to wait until 100%
and I cannot get the text nor attribute
I was trying to get_attribute('aria-valuenow').text but I assume thats not it.

```
while True:
            try:
                progress =  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".progress-bar.progress-bar-striped.active")))
                progressCondition =progress.get_attribute('aria-valuenow').text
                print(progressCondition)
                while True:
                    if progressCondition == '100':
                        break
                    else:
                        print(progress)
                        time.sleep(1)
                break
            except:
                print('Progress Not Found')
                time.sleep(1)
                timer += 1
                if timer > 30:
                    break
                else:
                    continue
```

how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with stackoverflow I did not know that I need to accept answers I will do it thx anyway

Comment: You don't have to do that, but 1) This makes indication that the problem is resolved 2) It's a way to say "Thanks" to person who helped you. This gives some points both to you and to the person who helped you.

Comment: I got it sir thank you for letting me know that ! :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this can help:

1. Change `presence_of_element_located` by `visibility_of_element_located` since `presence_of_element_located` returns the web element while it is still not fully rendered, just exists on the page, but still not visible while `visibility_of_element_located` waits for more mature elements state when it is already visible.
2. Remove `.text` from `progress.get_attribute('aria-valuenow').text`
   `get_attribute()` method returns string value itself. While `.text` extracts text from web element.
   So your code may look like the following:

```py
progress =  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".progress-bar.progress-bar-striped.active")))
progressCondition =progress.get_attribute('aria-valuenow')
print(progressCondition)
```

Comment: sorry for late reply! I just waited for it works and it works well! Thank you! have a good day!

Comment: It's OK. You do not have to accept the answers automatically. In case it works - accept the answer, otherwise let the answerer know if it did not work, what error appeared etc.

Answer (score 0):

As the innerText/innerHTML will eventually turn out as ***100*** instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *xpath* and *innerText*:

  ```
  progress =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@role='progressbar' and text()='100%']")))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *aria-valuenow* attribute:

  ```
  progress =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@role='progressbar' and @aria-valuenow='100%']")))
  ```