# Get href link with selenium (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, parsing, xpath

I want get all href from subelements.
parent class is `search-content`
it has parent divs `card-col` and in these divs there is another 1 div and then href. I want to get just this href link

[image: It is image]

this is my code-->

```
el=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search-content-cards")))
el_hrefs=el.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@href]")
for i in el_hrefs:
    print(i)
```

output is many elements

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="f7c84bf8-c20c-4b70-8ba5-414e822bba21")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="1e078e8b-104f-4299-94b1-8741cf30f047")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="d8b4b5e0-6291-4fd2-ae04-faee245462d1")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="ef06e8ac-321c-40db-9f6c-40dd3a3b07de")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="e14cf667-1bf4-434c-b9a2-1c4f362398d2")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="8e549221-eca4-41cf-943d-3cb0f6f75d50")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="afd597fb-1bb0-48fb-8646-6c43cb17ab38")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="8f3a655e-d3cd-4748-934a-2c9000481ed3")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="a1706e30-fad0-4799-871f-c5a928c69009")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="156847c9-5d7f-4963-82fa-baaf2b8f6e7f")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0a4b52d1575e427e34d6b790a284c501", element="99c320b4-f6f1-4eb4-abec-4be4df790b71")>
```

who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` in your case is a `web element`, and to extract the `.text`, you should not just print `i`, it should be `print(i.text)`.

Moreover if you want to extract the `href` off of the `a tag`, then you should use `.get_attribute('href')`

Secondly, I think you should use `CSS_SELECTOR`

```
div.search-content-cards
```

instead of `CLASS_NAME`

Also **a tag is descendant**.

so your **effective code** should look like this:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.search-content-cards")))
el_hrefs = el.find_elements_by_xpath(".//descendant::a[@href]")
for i in el_hrefs:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: can u tell me what's mean  div in head? (div.search-content-cards) i can't access with only class name?

Comment: that div has a class  (name having multiple spaces), if you use the class name, Selenium won't be able to find any element cause of spaces, you can remove the spaces and put `.` in it to make a CSS selector.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the values of *href* attribute instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.search-content-cards a.d-block")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'search-content-cards')]//a[contains(@class, 'd-block')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```