# Python Selenium get "sold items" information from eBay Productpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I want to click on the following element "23 verkauft" on an eBay productpage you can see it on this screenshot:

[image: Element to click on]

Here is the HTMl Code of this Element:

[image: HTMl Code]

Here is my Code but the webdriver cant locate the element or can't click on it.

```
sold = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class, 'vi-txt-underline']")))
sold.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close enough. But you have to make to adjustments:

- Instead of `(By.XPATH, "//span[@class, 'vi-txt-underline']")` you need to use `(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='vi-txt-underline']")`
- Instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to use [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511)

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as ***23 verkauft*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "23 verkauft"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.vi-txt-underline"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='23 verkauft']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This was the solution i think. The Webdriver is able to click the element, but then the window closes directly. I could see that the new page was abput to load and then it closed itself. It seemed like a capture would occure on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with your locator.
Instead of

```py
//span[@class, 'vi-txt-underline']
```

It should be

```py
//a[@class='vi-txt-underline']
```

Also instead of `presence_of_element_located` you should use `visibility_of_element_located` since the former method will wait for more mature element state, not only presented on the page but also visible.
Also you can click on the element there directly, no need for the additional code line.
So your code could be

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='vi-txt-underline']"))).click()
```