# Python Selenium clicks on wrong element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I m trying to build a selenium automation. But i can't pass this problem :

I am trying to click an icon called Data inside of a webpage, but when adress the element, the code clicks another element.

This is the html source of the element:

```
<a id="EPM_CA_3_3" class="app-nav-label top-nav-label" tabindex="0">Data</a>
```

When the code is executed it clicks another element.

This is the html source of the WRONG element:

```
<a id="EPM_CA_2_0" class="app-nav-label top-nav-label" tabindex="0">Tasks</a>
```

And here is screenshot of the elements (correct and wrong one)
[elements of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTimQ.png)

As you can see that both of element has different text even so the code runs incorrectly.

And here is my python code:

```
try:
    elementinside = '//a[text() ="Data"]' 
    databutton = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, elementinside)))
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,elementinside)
    # element.click()
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()


except TimeoutException:
    print("signing in fail!")
```

I couldn't find out any answer from internet. Please assist.

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: if you are using chrome, and inspecting the element; try getting the FULL xpath of the object. based on what you have described it seems like you are clicking on the first item in an array of items which may mean you need to specify more clearly which item you intend to click on; getting the full xpath may help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce[WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Data"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='app-nav-label top-nav-label' and text()='Data']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```