# Is there any option to verify/assert element CheckBox is present using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to verify that the checkbox is present but didn't find the exact answer is it possible to check it using Selenium Python (Assert will be great solution).

This is my code:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]').click()
```

Now I need to verify whether element with xpath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]
```

is present ot not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify that the checkbox is present ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: perfect solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check state of object, you can use [is_selected()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) function.

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]').is_selected()`