# Selenium trying to get elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'd like to get the elements by Selenium as the attached pic:

```
ess-cell class="data-numeric"
```

However, the following code didn't work even though:

```
find_element_by_tag_name('div')
```

part works correctly. Does anyone know why?

```
row.find_element_by_tag_name('div').find_element_by_tag_name('div').find_elements_by_tag_name('ess-cell')
```

[image]

Comment: `row.find_element_by_tag_name('div').find_element_by_tag_name('div').find_elements_by_tag_name('ess-cell')` parts works, that's fine. What is the error though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the elements `<ess-cell class="data-numeric"...>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  elements = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > div ess-cell.data-numeric")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  elements = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./div/div//ess-cell[contains(@class, 'data-numeric')]")
  ```

---

Ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*presence_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(row, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > div ess-cell.data-numeric")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(row, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "./div/div//ess-cell[contains(@class, 'data-numeric')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```