# Unable to click label that doesn't have any text using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click the label below.

Label html:

```
<div class="is-inline-block">
  <input id="entradas-checkbox-condiciones" type="checkbox" class="switch is-rounded is-small">
  <label style="padding-left:1rem;">
```

I've tried clicking the label with this code:

```
WebDriverWait = wait

label1 = wait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class = 'is-inline-block']")))[3]
label1.find_element_by_xpath('//label[style="padding-left:1rem;"]').click()
```

But i get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Can somebody help me with the code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate and invoke [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.is-inline-block input.switch.is-rounded.is-small#entradas-checkbox-condiciones"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='is-inline-block']//input[@class='switch is-rounded is-small' and @id='entradas-checkbox-condiciones']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: it worked tysm!