# How to find an element by a known src attribute using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to find an element by using Selenium with python, by a known value of src attribute. The element is the point picture on the left of the address of a location in Google Maps.

Namely the html for the element I'm trying to select:

```
<img alt="" jstcache="935" src="//www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/1x/place_gm_blue_24dp.png" class="Liguzb" jsan="7.Liguzb,0.alt,8.src">
```

How can I select the given element by searching for it by using the link:

```
www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/1x/place_gm_blue_24dp.png
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element as the value of *`src`* attribute is know to you, you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.Liguzb[src*='gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/1x/place_gm_blue_24dp']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class='Liguzb' and contains(@src, 'gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/1x/place_gm_blue_24dp')]")
  ```

---

To locate a ***visible*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.Liguzb[src*='gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/1x/place_gm_blue_24dp']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='Liguzb' and contains(@src, 'gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system_gm/1x/place_gm_blue_24dp')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```