# Python with selenium: unable to locate element which really exists

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, element

```
while len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@title='Next page']"))!=0:
```

The element is not found (and the while loop skept), I tried adding a timer

```
ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@title='Next Page']")))
```

Still impossible to make selenium recognize the element. I don't think I saw anything that looked like an iframe on the source (I might have missed it).

Comment: Please post the relevant html or share the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@title='Next Page']"))).click()
```

Comment: To start the loop I would first need to check if there is a 'next page' element. If so I need to click on the next page element once I am inside the while loop. My problem is in testing the presence of this element.

Comment: Did you try the code in the answer? Are you still facing the same issue?