# Can't access text when using selenium with python - possibly disabled

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, disabled-input

I am having issues accessing the text saying '-175'.

[website html (not sure how to post the screenshot!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsQWT.png)

I failed when trying this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="my-bets-history-possible-win ng-hide"]/span[2]').text
```

I have also enabled the disabled parts of the html by using this:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="second-color ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty"]')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("disabled");', button)
```

Any further ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text ***-175*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.my-bets-history-possible-win.ng-hide span::nth-of-type(2)"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class="my-bets-history-possible-win ng-hide"]//following::span[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. The text '-175', is not actually visible on the webpage which leads me to believe that it has been disabled. Furthermore, does get_attribute() work here as the text is not from an attribute, it is currently stored as text, right?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: yep, the following imports had already been added. Did you update with anything else?

Comment: I think the solution may be in changing the html from "my-bets-history-possible-win ng-hide" to "my-bets-history-possible-win". Is there a way to do this? (I did it manually and I could find it using .text

Comment: @rngaebzzbz The fact is you have shared an image of the HTML which doesn't helps in testing the solution. A text based HTML would have helped.