# How to accept a cookie consent with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to accept cookies consent with Selenium Python. I tried to search with CSS selector and XPath but nothing works.
This is the HTML:

```
<button class="sc-1epc5np-0 dnGUzk sc-f7uhhq-2 coEmEP button button--filled button__acceptAll" type="button"><span theme="[object Object]" class="sc-1vlt5h-0 sc-1epc5np-1 cMLEOX baseText">Accept Cookies</span></button>
    <span theme="[object Object]" class="sc-1vlt5h-0 sc-1epc5np-1 cMLEOX baseText">Accept Cookies</span>
</button>
```

I tried the following code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-1vlt5h-0.sc-1epc5np-1.cMLEOX.baseText')))
```

I also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("cMLEOX").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cMLEOX").click()
```

Nothing works. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click() on the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button__acceptAll > span.baseText"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'button__acceptAll')]/span[text()='Accept Cookies']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```