# How to extract validation message using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am unable to extract validation messages using get text in selenium
my HTML is

```
<div class="ant-alert-message"\>The email address or the password is incorrect. Please re-enter.</div\>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To print the validation message *`The email address or the password is incorrect. Please re-enter.`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ant-alert-message").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ant-alert-message'][contains(., 'address or the password')]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ant-alert-message"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ant-alert-message'][contains(., 'address or the password')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```