# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException error using send_keys() from Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

getting the error of timeout, tried to increase the time to 20, I see the page loading but still get the error and cannot see the email inserted to the field.

Code trials:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'input]'))
)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@class=input]').send_keys('test@em.com')
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'input]'))

element.sendKeys('test@em.com')
```

or

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'input]'))

element.sendKeys('test@em.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following *locator strategy*:

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="input"]'))).send_keys("test@em.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```