# Clicking on dropdown menu element works in Pycharm but not in server

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

There is a dropdown menu in which I need to click on the 2 item in list. So it works perfectly in Pycharm but not on server.

Code trials:

```
goods_count = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/main/div/div[*]/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", goods_count)`
```

What could be the difference between Pycharm and server side?

Answer (score 0):

To click on any ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following *locator strategy*:

```
goods_count = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]'))) 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", goods_count)
```

In a single line:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]'))))
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Got error in Pycharm: path:filename.py:63: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 116, in <module>
    goods_count = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
  File "path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
 Ordinal0 [0x00F27413+2389011]
 ...

Comment: Saw answers increasing wait value can helps - nope

Comment: There was an error in the xpath, corrected it. Please retest and let me know the ststus.

Comment: Error even with correct xpath

File "path/file.py", line 105, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
  File "path\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Doesn't the code in the answer work in _Pycharm_ as it worked earlier?

Comment: First, code worked in Pycharm but not on server. Now it doesn't even in Pycharm

Comment: See the embedded discussions for ` presence_of_element_located()` and `element_to_be_clickable()` within the answer. May be not the desired element.

Comment: A wild guess the `li` elements should be hidden and you need to expand the `<li>` elements clicking on some other element.