# How can I scrape the position of the players in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

If you visit this site,
https://www.premierleague.com/players,
you will be able to see a list of players with their positions and Nationality.
I am only required to scrape the position but I am unable to

```
playerss = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr')

for player in playerss:
    position = player.find_element(By.XPATH,'//[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
    print(position)
```

This is what I have but it is not working. If anyone knows how to help, I will appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you consider beautifulsoup instead?

Comment: I don't know beautifulsoup, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to get the list of positions:

```
...
driver.get('https://www.premierleague.com/players')
positions = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
                                 'table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)')

for pos in positions:
    print(pos.text)
```

if you have to use xpath:

```
positions = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the players are within:

```
<td class="hide-s">Midfielder</td>
```

where the *`<td>`* is having *class* as *`hide-s`*

---

### Solution

To print the *positions* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2)")))])
  ```
- Using *`innerHTML`*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2)")))])
  ```
- Using *`innerText`*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerText") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2)")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Midfielder', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Forward', 'Forward', 'Forward', 'Defender', 'Goalkeeper', 'Forward', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Midfielder', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Midfielder', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Defender', 'Midfielder', 'Goalkeeper', 'Midfielder', 'Midfielder', 'Midfielder', 'Defender', 'Midfielder', 'Forward', 'Forward']
  ```