# Python selenium not detecting button

Tags: python, selenium

My selenium python script can't click the button with either `click()` or `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", continue_). It worked for previous buttons but this particular button is only detected but can't be clicked.

Here is the code:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]")))
continue_ = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", continue_)
```

[image]

**Update:**
The answers didn't work for me. I tried adding prints to see where it stops.

```
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]")))
        print("Presence Located")
        continue_ = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]")
        print("Continue Button Found")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", continue_)
        print("Continue Button Clicked")
```

My console displays all prints till the "Continue Button Clicked" but is still not clicking the Continue so my bot can't progress through it's script. I don't know if it's any help but can't think of anything else.

**Update**
Tried using is_displayed() on the continue button it returned True.

Comment: Is the content in a frame? If so you might need to `switch_to.frame()`.

Comment: Please update the question with HTML source

Comment: Updated the question to another button but with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The *`<button>`* element have the *innerText* spanned over multiple lines.

---

### Solution

To click on the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`starts-with()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit' and starts-with(., 'Continue')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit' and contains(., 'Continue')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me.