# Xpath using using random.randint(2,8) always identifies the first item using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, random, webdriverwait

Working on a random question picker from a codechef webpage but the problem is even when i am using random value of i, it always clicks the first question.

Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import random

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.codechef.com/practice?page=0&limit=20&sort_by=difficulty_rating&            sort_order=asc&search=&start_rating=0&end_rating=999&topic=&tags=&group=all")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
time.sleep(3)

# element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Roller Coaster")

i = random.randint(2,8)

try:
    item = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[2]/div/a"))
)
    item.click()

except:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two simple tweaks as follows:

- To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447).
- You need to replace the single quotes i.e. `'+str(i)+'` with double quotes *`"+str(i)+"`*
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.codechef.com/practice?page=0&limit=20&sort_by=difficulty_rating&sort_order=asc&search=&start_rating=0&end_rating=999&topic=&tags=&group=all")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#gdpr-i-love-cookies"))).click()
  i = random.randint(2,8)
  print(i)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[2]/div/a"))).click()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  7
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Xpath to the following f-String and it will work perfectly:

Change this: `"/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[2]/div/a"`

To this: `f"/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]/div/a"`