# How to get around the StaleElementReferenceException with ignored_exceptions?

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling, wait, staleelementreferenceexception

So I am having a little difficulty with selenium automated testing.

I have a "next" button to click after filling in some fields, however, I get a `"selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"`

I have tried an explicit wait, ignoring this exception, however, it doesn't work.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)
your_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'c8')))

driver.find_element(By.ID, 'c8').click()
```

This doesn't work. It keeps throwing the error!

BUT!

If I add a time.sleep(0.5), then it will click the button.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'c8').click()
```

Now I know its bad practice to use time.sleep(), and I of course do want to use explicit waits for this, however, it's just not working for me.

I also tried an implicit wait, however, this literally just waits for the entire time that I set it to wait for, and then the next button can be clicked. I want to rather have the next button clicked as soon as it is able to be clicked.

Can anyone assist me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*`element_to_be_clickable()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)
your_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'c8')))

driver.find_element(By.ID, 'c8').click()
```