# TimeoutException while extracting the value of the title attribute using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am trying to get the following count of an Instagram account. I believe that the XPATH is correct an exists. Here's a screenshot showing it exists when I search for it:

[image: screenshot]

This is my code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)    
followers = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/button/div/span")))
print(followers.get_attribute("title"))
```

I have even looked at similar projects that find the following count and our code is almost exactly the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to locate the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(., 'followers')]//span[@class and @title and text()]"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```