# How to find the product name and price using the python scraper?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am writing a selenium based webscraper in python and it keeps throwing:

```
no such element: unable to locate element
```

Even though I can see the element in the selenium browser that is launched.
here is the link it keeps failing on:
https://www.neimanmarcus.com/p/givenchy-g-chain-ring-prod250190244?childItemId=NMY5X1R_&navpath=cat000000_cat4870731_cat50910737_cat2650734&page=0&position=11

Here is my code for the driver:

```
def getDriver():
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
        return driver
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print(Exception)
```

Here is the scraper:

````
def getProduct(domain, url):
    # find the yaml file for the domain
    driver = getDriver()

    noYaml = False
    try:
        markupPath = 'markups/%s.yml' % domain
    except Exception as error:
        noYaml = True
    if(noYaml == False):
        with open(markupPath, 'r') as file:
            yamlElements = yaml.safe_load(file)

        titleXpath = '//span[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," Titlestyles__ProductName-fRyAwr ")]'
        priceXpath = '//span[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," Pricingstyles__RetailPrice-eYMMwV ")]'
        print("XXXXXXPATHHHHHHHHHHHHHS: ",titleXpath, priceXpath)
        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        try:
            # WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,titleXpath)))
            
            title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, titleXpath)
        except Exception as error:
            print("ERROR: ", error)
            title = None

        try: 
            # WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,priceXpath)))
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(priceXpath)
            # price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,priceXpath)
            print(price)
        except Exception as error:
            print("ERRROR: ", error)
            price = None
        driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        data={}
        if(title != None):
            print(title.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
            data['title'] = title.get_attribute('innerHTML')

        if(price != None):
            print(price.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
            data['price'] = price.get_attribute('innerHTML')

        if 'price' not in data or data['price'] == "" or data['price'] == None:
            driver.quit()
            return False
            getProduct(domain, url)
        driver.quit()
        return data```

I have been stuck here for a while and can't figure out why it is throwing an error 
  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," Pricingstyles__RetailPrice-eYMMwV ")]"}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that website will automatically redirect visitor according to the country determined from visitor's IP, and it will also change the classes for item name and price accordingly. Here is a more robust solution, which will account for such changes, and will also wait for the element to load in page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-jp/p/givenchy-g-chain-ring-prod250190244?childItemId=NMY5X1R_&navpath=cat000000_cat4870731_cat50910737_cat2650734&page=0&position=11'

browser.get(url) 

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "closeButton"))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print('no pop-up, moving on')

title = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-test='pdp-title']")))
price = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test='pdp-pricing']")))
print(title.text.strip(), price.text.strip())
```

Result:

```
G-Chain Ring JPY 46709
```

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the *xpaths* i.e. `fRyAwr`, `eYMMwV` are dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

To print the product name and price instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-in/p/givenchy-g-chain-ring-prod250190244?childItemId=NMY5X1R_&navpath=cat000000_cat4870731_cat50910737_cat2650734&page=0&position=11'})
  # Close Now shipping to India popup
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#closeButton"))).click()
  # Close cookie consent
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.close_button_panel>i.close_icon"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-test='pdp-title']"))).text)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test='pdp-pricing']>span"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-in/p/givenchy-g-chain-ring-prod250190244?childItemId=NMY5X1R_&navpath=cat000000_cat4870731_cat50910737_cat2650734&page=0&position=11'})
  # Close Now shipping to India popup
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='closeButton']"))).click()
  # Close cookie consent
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='close_button_panel']/i[@class='close_icon']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-test='pdp-title']"))).text)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test='pdp-pricing']/span"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  G-Chain Ring
  INR 27573
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: you were correct, those selectors are better. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your xpaths are missing the last bit of the string. You may want to consider simplifying them as well by doing this:

```
titleXpath = '//span[@class="Titlestyles__ProductName-fRyAwr elVgyx"]'
priceXpath = '//span[@class="Pricingstyles__RetailPrice-eYMMwV jjJaCp"]'
```

And also, if you are still recieving the error you may want to look into adding a user agent to your webdriver options. Hope this helps

Comment: those xpaths and user agent both not working. The data appars in my selectlib extension with the xpaths I use. I don't know why i doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble debugging your xpaths, and I am too--they are hard to read. These CSS Selectors work for me:

```
CssSelectorTitle = 'span.Titlestyles__ProductName-fRyAwr'
CssSelectorPrice = 'span.Pricingstyles__RetailPrice-eZcFGu'
```

Comment: when using selectlib extension for chrome those xpaths work. It only fails in the code. I fixed my wrong quotes in my original posts for the xpaths.

Comment: how can these xpath's work for selectlib and fail on selenium. I see the chrome window open and the elements are present

Comment: This is aa CSS selector, not xpath, may I assume you're trying that?

Comment: (Your xpath doesn't work for me from devtools)

Comment: css selectors are giving me the same error