# Selenium Python: Element is not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, partiallinktext

I am testing a webapp created with python dash using selenium. I am trying to click a tab but always get the `ElementClickIntercepted Exception`.

Note: Of course I stumbled over similiar problems but most times the problem is that the element cannot be clicked as is did not load yet - I already built in waits! - or the fact that another element would receive the click which cannot be the case either. Note that the first item is always preselected and i want to choose the second.

```
#Selct X-Axis
x_axis = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='navbar']/a[2]")
x_axis.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Even']"))  
)
except:
    raise Exception
even= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Even']")
even.click()
```

Exception snapshot:

[image: The Exception]

HTML snapshot:

[image: The html-code]

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example and add your code in the post?

Comment: Nobody can help you without an actual reproducible example

Comment: Sorry, now I will add it

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted, `By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Even']"` is probably selecting an HTML element different from what you're expecting.

There appears to be an `<a>` with text that *starts* with `'Even'`, but you've shown nothing with text that *equals* `'Even'`.

BTW, when asking a question, you ought to at least paste the relevant HTML as text, rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: I get your point. But I just greyed the whole text out as I dont want everybody to know the whole text. Of course I am selecting ```By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Even wordxy']"```: This will not solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains(text(), 'even')` instead of `text()='even'` in your XPath. Because, `text()='even'` means the text must be 'even' but not contain 'even', and in your HTML code, the text seems not only have 'even'.

Comment: I get your point. But I just greyed the whole text out as I dont want everybody to know the whole text. Of course I am selecting By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Even wordxy']": This will not solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

To click on either of the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *$$$ Response*:

  - Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Response"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'content')]//ul//div[@class='nav-item']//a[contains(., 'Response')]"))).click()
    ```
- *Even $$$*:

  - Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Even"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id, 'content')]//ul//div[@class='nav-item']//a[starts-with(., 'Even')]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: If you compare to what I did in the source code, you will recognize that this is basically what I did. ALready had your tools imported...
Even though I tried with your code, the error stayed the same.

Comment: _"this is basically what I did"_ is quite different from what exactly have been suggested.

Comment: I used the webdriver wait statement as well as theexpected conditions, and even with the partial link solution the error is the same