# Cant locate iframe by contains in xPath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, iframe

Trying to access this iframe but cannot seem to target it. While using xpath I have to use contain as the iframe id is always changing the last numbers.

```
<iframe id="cardinal-stepUpIframe-1659117883889" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" name="cardinal-stepUpIframe-1659117883889"></iframe>
```

I currently have the following code to try and access the iframe. I have tried accessing it via //* which does not seem to work either.

```
newiframe = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@id, 'cardinal-stepUpIframe')]")))
driver.switch_to.frame(newiframe)
print('switched to frame')
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to the [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *`id`* attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='cardinal-stepUpIframe']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`name`* attribute:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'cardinal-stepUpIframe')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: The iframe was actually located within an iframe that I failed to spot earler. However, frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it is better than presence_of_element_located