# Python Selenium send_keys writes only one character in WhatsaApp Web's message box

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp, sendkeys

I'm trying to send automatic messages on WhatsApp Web (MacOS, Firefox), I want to use Selenium (pywhatkit also works), but send_keys sends only the first one character.

All the "import" of the code
`from selenium import webdriver`
`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`
`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`
`from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service`
`import time`

`TXT_BAR='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]'`

```
txt_bar = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, TXT_BAR)))

txt_bar.click()
txt_bar.clear()

txt_bar.send_keys("help")
time.sleep(5)
txt_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
#output -> h
```

edited code:

```
txt_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, TXT_BAR)))
txt_bar.click()
txt_bar.clear()
txt_bar.send_keys("help")
txt_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#output -> h
```

Answer (score 1):

I have facing a similar problem like this. May be this is a security measure used facebook to prevent automation.
one particular solution is to use a  loop. Here is a example:
Texts="hello, world"
For text in texts:
send_keys(text)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp web elements are dynamic elements. Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
txt_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, TXT_BAR)))
txt_bar.click()
txt_bar.clear()
txt_bar.send_keys("help")
txt_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: What error do you see? Remember we still don't know anything about `TXT_BAR`

Comment: Right, it makes sense, but when I correct my code, the problem remains.                                                                                      I’m sorry but I’m new to formatting comments on Stackoverflow, there’s no "error" I think, `TXT_BAR  = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]'  `should be right, I can see the character.

Comment: `txt_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, TXT_BAR)))
    txt_bar.click()
    txt_bar.clear()
    txt_bar.send_keys("help")
    txt_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`   The output it's still "h".

Comment: I have already added these import.