# How to locate the email address element with a Facebook page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So I am trying to first pull the body where the email address lies on this specific facebook page and then pull the email address plus other attributes within that body. However, I have tried every way to locate these elements using Chropath, and SelectorHub but nothing has worked. Any idea why I am unable to use these tools?

Code trials:

```
from ast import Return
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Carson/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/TheVillageAtGracyFarms")
driver.maximize_window()
try: 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body._6s5d._71pn.system-fonts--body.segoe:nth-child(2) div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb:nth-child(6) div.du4w35lb.l9j0dhe7.cbu4d94t.j83agx80 div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.l9j0dhe7 div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.l9j0dhe7.jgljxmt5.be9z9djy.qfz8c153 div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d6urw2fd.dp1hu0rb.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb:nth-child(1) div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.dp1hu0rb:nth-child(1) div.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.buofh1pr.dp1hu0rb.hpfvmrgz div.l9j0dhe7.dp1hu0rb.cbu4d94t.j83agx80 div.bp9cbjyn.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d2edcug0:nth-child(4) div.rq0escxv.d2edcug0.ecyo15nh.k387qaup.r24q5c3a.hv4rvrfc.dati1w0a.tr9rh885:nth-child(2) div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.pfnyh3mw.gs1a9yip.j83agx80.btwxx1t3.lhclo0ds.taijpn5t.sv5sfqaa.o22cckgh.obtkqiv7.fop5sh7t div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.hpfvmrgz.g5gj957u.aov4n071.oi9244e8.bi6gxh9e.h676nmdw.aghb5jc5.o387gat7.g1e6inuh.fhuww2h9.rek2kq2y:nth-child(1) div.lpgh02oy:nth-child(2) div.sjgh65i0 div.j83agx80.l9j0dhe7.k4urcfbm div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.hybvsw6c.io0zqebd.m5lcvass.fbipl8qg.nwvqtn77.k4urcfbm.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.sbcfpzgs div.sej5wr8e div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.j83agx80.pfnyh3mw.i1fnvgqd.gs1a9yip.owycx6da.btwxx1t3.hv4rvrfc.dati1w0a.discj3wi.b5q2rw42.lq239pai.mysgfdmx.hddg9phg:nth-child(2) > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb.j83agx80.cbu4d94t.d2edcug0.hpfvmrgz.rj1gh0hx.buofh1pr.g5gj957u.p8fzw8mz.pcp91wgn.iuny7tx3.ipjc6fyt")))
    print("Dub")
except:
    print("Failed")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try to locate the element by its `XPATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***Email Address*** field within the [webpage](https://www.facebook.com/TheVillageAtGracyFarms) contains dynamic elements.

To locate the ***Email Address*** field instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and the text `@`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@')]"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and the texts `@` & `com`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '@') and contains(., 'com')]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks the visibility of the element worked perfectly. What is the difference between presence of element and the visibility of an element? Based on the name, those sound very similar. I still don't see why the presence of elements didn't work beforehand.

Comment: @CarsonCramer Check the hyperlinks to each of the terms. I trust those will clear all your doubts. Else we can discuss further in the [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.