# Selenium can not find elements in dynamic web page, page source does not be loaded completely

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic, selenium-chromedriver

I try to recover some elements in a web page with selenium but the page_source I'm getting it does not have that elements loaded.

Find element returns elem.text empty and driver.page_source does not have the id titulotramitedocu.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
URL = "https://seu.conselldemallorca.net/fitxa?key=91913"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    elem = driver.find_element(By.ID,"titulotramitedocu")
    print(elem.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I also tried with a wait..

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "titulotramitedocu"))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate and print the text from the ***visible*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.titulotramitedocu#titulotramitedocu > h1"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='titulotramitedocu' and @id='titulotramitedocu']//h1"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Concurs de mèrits de personal funcionari del Consell de Mallorca per a la categoria d'enginyer-a tècnic-a industrial d'administració especial (codi CFCEA2/024)
  ```

Comment: Should this solution works for key=90916? could it need more time to get the value?