# How to find the starting value of a dynamic element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

Im trying to get the value of the timer in the following website:
https://userinyerface.com/game.html
The timer starts from zero, however the problem is that when I retrieve the timer with selenium using the following python code:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def test_path(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://userinyerface.com/game.html")
    try:
        timer_is_displayed = WebDriverWait(driver,
        10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div//div[1]//div[2]//div[2]                                 //div')))
        timer = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div//div[1]//div[2]//div[2]//div')
        print(timer.text)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

it prints the timer as 00:00:02, if add time.sleep(1) it returns an error as the page did not have time to load before looking for the element. If I do time.sleep(2) it returns 00:00:02, how can I check that the timer starts from 00:00:00? is there a way to find the starting value of that particular element?

I've tried using explicit waits to no avail.

Comment: Welcome Valente! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Maybe this is because `driver.get` blocks until the page is fully loaded, at which point the timer has already advanced two seconds. Not sure if there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need and should not hardcoded pauses.
`WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` should be used.
You need to wait for the moment when the page is loaded and timer element is **visible**.
This is the moment when you need to take the value from there.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://userinyerface.com/game.html"
driver.get(url)
initial_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "timer"))).text
print(initial_value)
```

The output is:

```
00:00:00
```

**UPD**
You could locate the timer element with XPath or CSS Selector as well. It's no the issue how to locate element, the point here is to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions`.
For example you can use this line:

```py
initial_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='timer timer--white timer--center']"))).text
```

Insteaqd of

```py
initial_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "timer"))).text
```

It gives absolutely the same result.

Comment: That is super weird! any idea why using xpath as a locator outputs "00:00:02"? It works perfectly now thanks!

Comment: @ValenteSaavedraFdz it's not about how to locate the element. You could use Xpath as well, see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the initial value of the timer i.e. ***00:00:00*** from the [website](https://userinyerface.com/game.html) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `timer` class:

  ```
  driver.get("https://userinyerface.com/game.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.timer"))).text) #00:00:00
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `timer--white` class:

  ```
  driver.get("https://userinyerface.com/game.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.timer--white"))).text) #00:00:00
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `timer--center` class:

  ```
  driver.get("https://userinyerface.com/game.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.timer--center"))).text) #00:00:00
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and  all the classes:

  ```
  driver.get("https://userinyerface.com/game.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.timer.timer--white.timer--center"))).text) #00:00:00
  ```
- Using [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://userinyerface.com/game.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.timer.timer--white.timer--center"))).text) #00:00:00
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: When reading web element text content it's better to wait for element visibility, not just presence...

Comment: @Prophet When the question is how quick you can reach to the destination, `presence` may be prefered over `visibility`. However you possibly missed the last option with _`visibility_of_element_located()`_

Comment: OP asked how to validate the timer starts with `00:00:00`. Actually he want's to extract the element text value, as I do in my code. I actually run it and I actualy got that result

Comment: @Prophet You mentioned _"Actually he want's to extract the element text value"_ and _"I actualy got that result"_: Is my solution doing something else? Did you execute my code?

Comment: I know, in most cases waiting for element presence will work. But still. If we want to extract the element text it is more correct to wait for elements visibility. And in case element should be clicked we should wait for element clickability.

Comment: @Prophet Sounds great. Seems now you have learned the core difference between presence/visibility/interactibility.

Comment: It's not higher mathematics :)