# Use driver.find_element("id","") can not find

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to click button

```
<p class="btn" id="LargeNextBtn" style=""><a href="javascript:fnNextStep('P');" id="LargeNextBtnLink" onfocus="this.blur();"><img src="//ticketimage.globalinterpark.com/ticketimage/Global/Play/onestop/G2001/btn_next_on.gif" id="LargeNextBtnImage" alt=""> </a></p>
```

but when I use find_element

```
driver.find_element("id", "LargeNextBtn").click()
```

can't find "LargeNextBtn"

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="LargeNextBtn"]"}
```

I also try to into iframe but it also fail

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"ifrmBookStep")))
```

[image]

Any help or pointers is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Use implicit wait and check whether you can find the element. If it works, then it's waiting problem.

Comment: i try add  driver.implicitly_wait(5) before driver.find_element("id", "LargeNextBtn").click(). it's also fail.

Comment: _Any help or pointers is appreciated_: Did you get a chance to check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339133/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.btn#LargeNextBtn > a#LargeNextBtnLink > img#LargeNextBtnImage").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='btn' and @id='LargeNextBtn']/a[@id='LargeNextBtnLink']/img[@id='LargeNextBtnImage']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.btn#LargeNextBtn > a#LargeNextBtnLink > img#LargeNextBtnImage"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='btn' and @id='LargeNextBtn']/a[@id='LargeNextBtnLink']/img[@id='LargeNextBtnImage']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thank you reply. and i tried , but it also failed.

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='btn' and @id='LargeNextBtn']/a[@id='LargeNextBtnLink']/img[@id='LargeNextBtnImage']"))).click()
  File "/Users/zhuwenping/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the `p` tag.

You also need to change the `style` **attribute** to `display : block` use `javascripts executor` to change the `style` of the element.

**Code:**

```
pTag=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"LargeNextBtn")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", pTag)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a#LargeNextBtnLink"))).click()
```

Comment: Isn't the `LargeNextBtn` element out of the scope of `<iframe>`?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium, Ah, yes you are right! I have updated, snapshot is always a challenge :-D

Comment: thank you reply. and i tried .but i also failed on pTag=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"LargeNextBtn")))

Comment: @booboo, Don’t switch to iframe.as element is not inside the iframe. Removed the line you have added for iframe and try my code again. Hope that works.

Comment: i didn't add any switch element.it also can not work.

Comment: Well.is it possible to share the link?

Comment: i want dut this it a little diffcult to share link. because this link it is need to login and after click a botton.

Comment: https://www.globalinterpark.com/detail/edetail?prdNo=23001060&dispNo=01003 select a date and click the buy ticket. will show the link

Answer (score 0):

The element you want is not inside the IFRAME so you don't have to switch contexts. Instead of targeting the P tag, I would instead target the A itself since it has an ID.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "LargeNextBtnLink"))).click()
```