# How to find the the CloudFlare human verification element using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, cloudflare, webdriverwait

The browser is FireFox and the language is Python.I am unable to complete the CloudFlare human verification.

In this website(https://chat.openai.com/chat), I'm unable to find the "mark" element by this code:

```
verify=WebDriverWait(driver, 10,0.1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mark')))
```

HTML:

[image]

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ,
    verify=WebDriverWait(driver, 10,0.1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mark')))
  File "...Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16
```

Why and how to fix it.

Comment: Note that this element might be inside an `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

The element `<span class="mark>...</mark>` have a visible text in it. So to identify the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.ctp-checkbox-label span.mark")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='ctp-checkbox-label']//span[@class='mark']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```