# How to input some text into input field using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Code trials:

```
voucher_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.NAME, "voucher")))
```

I tried changing the name for input field in code still didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relevant HTML of the element being:

```
<input name="voucher" ...>
```

To send a *character sequence* to the element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *NAME*:

  ```
  voucher_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "voucher")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  voucher_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='voucher']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  voucher_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='voucher']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

After locating the input field, you can use the send_keys() method to input text into it.

```
voucher_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "voucher")))
voucher_input.send_keys("your text here")
```