# How to click on facebook create new account button using Selenium Script

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, partiallinktext

I am trying to run a selenium script for facebook create new account button. But am not able to click the create new account button via selenium script. Here is the code I am using below. I am getting error of:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

But is neither retrivable by class or ID. Please suggest!!!!

Code:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
WebElement sign_in= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='u_0_0_DX']"));
sign_in.click();
driver.close();
```

I am trying to run a selenium script for facebook new user signup but am not able to click the singup page button via selenium script.

Comment: _facebook new user signup_: Do you mean **Create new account** button?

Comment: Yes, it's create new account button. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: what is the use case for this? after all, you can only have one account on facebook anyway afaik...

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below if you want to click this button:

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
# Click on Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@data-testid='cookie-policy-manage-dialog-accept-button'])[2]"))).click()
# Click on Create new account button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-testid='open-registration-form-button']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The *id* attribute values like *`u_0_0_DX`*, *`u_0_0_A5`* are dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

To click on <kbd>Create new account</kbd> you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *partial_link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Create new account").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Create new account')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Create new account"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Create new account')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Facebook_SignUp]