# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys' using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm using selenium python and I have this code, it finds a comment box and then I want to type there a comment.
the code finds the comment box but when it tries to type something the code breakes and i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys.
```

Thats the code:

```
no_show = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpath")
        no_show.click()
        notes = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("id","the id")))
        time.sleep(2)
        notes = driver.find_element("id", "__area0-inner").click() #(The code fails here)
        notes.send_keys("test")
        print("test passed")
```

I tried another explicit wait:

```
element2 = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("id","the id")))
```

I tried to use `notes.clear()`
Didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, your problem is here:

```
        notes = driver.find_element("id", "__area0-inner").click() #(The code fails here)
        notes.send_keys("test")
```

The problem is that instead of saving the found element, you immediately call .click() on it and save result of that - which is None because clicking doesn't return any data! Split into multiple lines, to actually save the element:

```
        notes = driver.find_element("id", "__area0-inner")
        notes.click()
        notes.send_keys("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys.
```

...implies that `send_keys()` can't be invoked on *`NoneType`* objects.

---

### This usecase

`click()` doesn't return anything. So *`notes`* remains *NULL*/unassigned in the line:

```
notes = driver.find_element("id", "__area0-inner").click()
```

Hence when you try to invoke `send_keys()` on *`notes`*

```
notes.send_keys("test")
```

you see the error.

---

### Solution

To invoke `send_keys()` on an element you don't need to invoke `click()` initially and can invoke `send_keys()` directly once the element is identified. Additionally instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_cssSelector"))).send_keys("test")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "element_xpath"))).send_keys("test")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: The problem is they they were immediately chaining into `.click()` and capturing its return value, which returns `None`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes champion, I misread the error. The error was on send_keys where as I took it on click :(

Comment: "So notes remains NULL/unassigned in the line:" - this is python, there's never "unassigned" after non-exception var= line. And we don't have `NULL` nor `null`, just `None`