# ElementNotInteractableException: Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, element

I am new in Selenium, here is the error that i showed up

**My code:**

```py
 def job_search(self):
        """This function goes to the 'Jobs' section and looks for all the jobs that match the keywords and location"""
    
        # Go to the LinkedIn job search page
        self.driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs")
    
        # Wait for the job search page to load fully
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jobs-search-box__text-input[aria-label='Search by title, skill, or company']")))
    
        # Search based on keywords and location
        search_keywords = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jobs-search-box__text-input[aria-label='City, state, or zip code']")
        search_keywords.clear()
        search_keywords.send_keys(self.keywords)
    
        # Wait for the search location input field to be interactable
        search_location = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jobs-search-box__input--location")))
        search_location.clear()
        search_location.send_keys(self.location)
        search_location.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**Here is the error that i got**

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134)
```

I want to interact with "Search bar" in LinkedIN, but unfortunately the error welcomed me

Comment: Which element is not interactable? At which line are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. The [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used to identify the search box, doesn't identifies the *Search Box* uniquely. Rather it identifies total ***3*** elements.

[image: 3elements]

---

### Solution

To locate the **clickable** element and send a character sequence instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447)you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.jobs-search-box__text-input.jobs-search-box__keyboard-text-input[aria-label='Search by title, skill, or company'][aria-activedescendant]"))).send_keys(self.keywords)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='jobs-search-box__text-input jobs-search-box__keyboard-text-input' and @aria-label='Search by title, skill, or company'][@aria-activedescendant]"))).send_keys(self.keywords)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I finally took a big step with the help of you.