# Differentiate by section class in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web

Im facing a problem in Python selenium,
I would like to print on my code the following data, an email address: caioplinio@hotmail.it

I just need a hint, that's all...

HTML:

```
<section tabindex="-1" class="pv-profile-section pv-contact-info artdeco-container-card">
<!---->
<h2 class="text-body-large-open mb4">
   Información de contacto
</h2>
<div class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info" tabindex="-1">
<section class="pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-vanity-url">
   <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="linkedin-bug" class="pv-contact-info__contact-icon" size="medium">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
         <path d="M20.5 2h-17A1.5 1.5 0 002 3.5v17A1.5 1.5 0 003.5 22h17a1.5 1.5 0 001.5-1.5v-17A1.5 1.5 0 0020.5 2zM8 19H5v-9h3zM6.5 8.25A1.75 1.75 0 118.3 6.5a1.78 1.78 0 01-1.8 1.75zM19 19h-3v-4.74c0-1.42-.6-1.93-1.38-1.93A1.74 1.74 0 0013 14.19a.66.66 0 000 .14V19h-3v-9h2.9v1.3a3.11 3.11 0 012.7-1.4c1.55 0 3.36.86 3.36 3.66z"></path>
      </svg>
   </li-icon>
   <h3 class="pv-contact-info__header t-16 t-black t-bold">
      Perfil de Marco
   </h3>
   <div class="pv-contact-info__ci-container t-14">
      <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com" class="pv-contact-info__contact-link link-without-visited-state t-14">
      mywebsite.com/italia/caio_plinio
      </a>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-email">
<li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="envelope" class="pv-contact-info__contact-icon">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
      <path d="M2 4v13a3 3 0 003 3h14a3 3 0 003-3V4zm18 2v1.47l-8 5.33-8-5.33V6zm-1 12H5a1 1 0 01-1-1V8.67L12 14l8-5.33V17a1 1 0 01-1 1z"></path>
   </svg>
</li-icon>
<h3 class="pv-contact-info__header t-16 t-black t-bold">
   Email
</h3>
<div class="pv-contact-info__ci-container t-14">
   <a href="mailto:  caioplinio@hotmail.it" class="pv-contact-info__contact-link link-without-visited-state t-14" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
   caioplinio@hotmail.it
   </a>
</div>
```

This is what I have wrote does, part of the code.

```
contact_info = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pv-contact-info__ci-container')))

# Find the email element within the contact info section
email_element = contact_info.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.pv-contact-info__contact-link')


email = email_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

print(email)
```

> Output: mywebsite.com/italia/caio_plinio

I see the problem is I am using  more than more time.

I see the solution is "differenciate" by *section class* but how can I write it? (I just need a hint)

[image]

My desired ouput:

> caioplinio@hotmail.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text ***caioplinio@hotmail.it*** instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*, `following-sibling` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(., 'Email') and contains(@class, 'pv-contact-info__header')]//following-sibling::div[1]/a"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*, `following` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(., 'Email') and contains(@class, 'pv-contact-info__header')]//following::div[1]/a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Using XPath locator, you can use the below code:**

```
email_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(text(),'Email')]//following::a[1]")
print (email_element.text)
```

Result:

```
caioplinio@hotmail.it
```

**XPath expression explanation:** Below XPath expression will locate the first `<a>` node which is located  immediately after the `<h3>` node containing text `Email`.

```
//h3[contains(text(),'Email')]//following::a[1]
```

2. **Using CLASS locator:**

In your code, just change below:

```
contact_info = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pv-contact-info__ci-container')))
```

To:

```
contact_info = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pv-contact-info__contact-type.ci-email')))
```

**Full working code:**

```
contact_info = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pv-contact-info__contact-type.ci-email')))

# Find the email element within the contact info section
email_element = contact_info.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.pv-contact-info__contact-link')

email = email_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(email)
```

Result:

```
caioplinio@hotmail.it
```